# Formula for ' constant-power' across 3 sound sources (3-way DJ Crossfader)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

First time poster here - thank you profusely in advance for any help you can provide!

***Intro/Context***

I need help to expand upon an existing mathematical approach to providing 'constant power' in context of a DJ crossfader (previous discussion here - [Simple Formula for Curve of DJ Crossfader volume : Dipped](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/simple-formula-for-curve-of-dj-crossfader-volume-dipped)).

In summary on this prior topic, two signals (e.g. two songs) are able to be faded between one another using a crossfader, which for example can go from x-axis position '0' (100% song A, 0% song B) to x-axis position '1' (0% song A, 100% song B).

A common equation to evaluate the combined power of each channel as the crossfader moves along the x-axis is $f(x) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$. This allows us to take any point on the x-axis, and the square of the two combined y-axis values, for each of the sound sources, will always = 1. This is the condition we must to meet to ensure constant power, since 'power' is sound pressure squared. For this equation, the y-axis is 'power', with y(1) being 100% power, and the x-axis is distance between the signal and the crossfader position (0 being 100%, 1 being 0% as the crossfader is positioned on the opposite side).  If you're a little confused, head over to the linked discussion to check out the graphs.

***My question!***

I have an equilateral triangle drawn on a flat plane (lets say the x,z plane). The coordinates of it's vertices are as follows :

(x,z)
Point A - (0,0)
Point B - (0.5,0.86602540378)
Point C - (1,0)

distance of all 3 sides = 1

In my application, these coordinates are the origins of 3 signals (sound sources) I have defined within a triangular cross-fader. Instead of fading between two sound sources using a 1-dimensional left to right fader as done in traditional mixers, I'd like to (using a touch screen interface), fade between 3 sound sources on a 2-dimensional plane whilst maintaining constant power (sum of all squared y-axis values  = 1).

I need to find an equation or a mathematical approach which will allow me to pick any point inside or on the border of my equilateral triangle (x,z plane), and have the sum of the squares of the 3 y-axis points equal 1 (much like $f(x) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$ on the 2-dimensional / 2 sound source).

The distance from one of the vertices will define the percentage of total power that particular source sound is granted. If it's 'on' the vertex, that means that distance is 0, therefore 100% of the sound comes form that source. In this instance, the distance from the other two vertices equals 1, therefore no power is granted to those signals.

My background in mathematics is not profoundly strong, and I'm at a loss as to how to build a x,y,z equation which fulfils these basic requirements. In my minds-eye, I can see 3 similar cos/sin function curved 360 degrees around in the z-plane, with the center point each being my 3 coordinates, with the sum of the squared y-axis values always being 1. But this is in my head :)

Another approach would be for me just to get a ratio of the 3 'distances' between point P and the sound sources (vertices), and somehow grant each their slice of the power pie as long as the sum of their squared y-axis values = 1...

I'd also like it to be as 'soft' as possible so the curvature of the graph which the equation defines doesn't have any points where the tangent is extreme.. this would mean one of my sound sources volume would ramp up / cut off too quickly.

Any ideas?

Many Many thanks for your time.

Hakon.